# OpenID Connect implementation (node.js typescript)

Tags: node.js, openid-connect

I'm implementing SSO login via a OpenID Connect Identity provider and I'm having trouble figuring out the authorisation flow. I've been reading a lot of different guides and documentations but since OIDC is so new all the guides vary and I can't seem to find a conclusive solution to the implementation.
I have a identity provider and the .well-known/openid-configuration site which should have everything I need to connect my RP (Relying Party) application to the IP (Identity Provider). I'm using node.js with typescript as my language.
If anyone has any proper documentation on OIDC or guides it would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to find code examples or videos about this but I just seem to find a lot of middleware solutions like okta and OneLogin, but I would like to use the certified node libraries like openid-client and so on, but the documentations seem abit lacking, or maybe I just haven't properly figured out how the flow works.

Thanks in advance guys!
Br,
Victor

Answer (score 1):

What type of app are you building in Nodejs? That affects the flow you will use ...Here is some sample nodejs code of mine - with some accompanying doc - but it is for an SPA and API - which may be different to your own requirements: https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the reply! I'm building a website application, and my backend will provide the OIDC implementation. I'm looking through your code as we speak and trying to figure out how it works. I already have the client and secret for the OIDC identity provider I will use, just haven't figured out how to handle the flow. Authorization code flow is apparently the one I will use.